# Is there a way to set the style of the nth child of a container in code-behind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a way to set the style of the nth child of container with code?

```
<StackPanel x:Name="container">
   <TextBlock x:Name="1st"/>
   <TextBlock x:Name="2nd"/>
   <TextBlock x:Name="3rd"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I want something like this:

```
container.children[2].Style = this.FindResource("style") as Style;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast the child to a derivative of [`FrameworkElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement?view=net-5.0) first, which declares the [`Style`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.style?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) property. In case of your code sample, you could cast the child to `TextBlock`.

```
var textBlock = (TextBlock)container.Children[2];
textBlock.Style = this.FindResource("style") as Style;
```

A more general solution would be to cast the child to `FrameworkElement` if there are other types.

```
var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)container.Children[2];
frameworkElement.Style = this.FindResource("style") as Style;
```

If your panel is not as static as in your example, you should check the bounds of `Children`, too, and if the child is really of type  `FrameworkElement` (if there could be other elements not derived from it).

```
if (container.Children.Count >= 2 && container.Children[2] is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
   frameworkElement.Style = this.FindResource("style") as Style;
```